# application exited and its hard to find the reason

Tags: android, mysql

I'm working on making app and put data into mysql.
It was okay when my classmate ran the project in her laptop.
But it's not working in my laptop.
I'm trying to solve the problem, but the application still stopped.
I don't know why..

Here is the code and the log

```
public class DateAndTime extends Activity {

    EditText Name, Mobile, Addrs, Fee;
    TextView Otime, Ctime;
    String pic,name, mobile, addrs, otime, ctime, fee;// 바꾸고 이미지도 추가.
    ImageView Pic;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    private TextView mText1;
    private TextView mText2;
    private Button mPickDate1;
    private Button mPickTime1;
    private Button mPickDate2;
    private Button mPickTime2;

    private int mYear1;
    private int mYear2;
    private int mMonth1;
    private int mMonth2;
    private int mDay1;
    private int mDay2;
    private int mHour1;
    private int mHour2;
    private int mMinute1;
    private int mMinute2;

    //Dialog
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_1 = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID_1 = 1;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_2 = 2;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID_2 = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.avtivity_date_time);

        mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mPickDate1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate1);
        mPickTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime1);

        mText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        mPickDate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate2);
        mPickTime2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime2);

        mPickDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_1);
            }
        });

        mPickDate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_2);
            }
        });

        mPickTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_1);
            }
        });

        mPickTime2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_2);
            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute1 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        mYear2 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth2 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay2 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour2 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute2 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        updateDisplay();

        Pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pic);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_owner);
        Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mob);
        Addrs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_addrs);
        Otime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Ctime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        Fee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_fee);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void updateDisplay() {
        mText1.setText(String.format("시작 : %d년 %d월 %d일 %d시 %d분", mYear1, mMonth1 + 1, mDay1, mHour1, mMinute1));
        mText2.setText(String.format("종료 : %d년 %d월 %d일 %d시 %d분", mYear2, mMonth2 + 1, mDay2, mHour2, mMinute2));
    }

    public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener1 =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear1 = year;
                    mMonth1 = monthOfYear;
                    mDay1 = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };
    public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener2 =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear2 = year;
                    mMonth2 = monthOfYear;
                    mDay2 = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener1 =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour1 = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute1 = minute;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener2 =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour2 = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute2 = minute;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID_1:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener1, mYear1, mMonth1, mDay1);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID_1:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener1, mHour1, mMinute1, false);

            case DATE_DIALOG_ID_2:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener2, mYear2, mMonth2, mDay2);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID_2:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener2, mHour2, mMinute2, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void saveInfo(View view) {
        pic = "default";
        name = Name.getText().toString();
        mobile = Mobile.getText().toString();
        addrs = Addrs.getText().toString();
        otime = Otime.getText().toString();
        ctime = Ctime.getText().toString();
        fee = Fee.getText().toString();
        DateAndTime.BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new DateAndTime.BackgroundTask();
        backgroundTask.execute(pic, name,  mobile, addrs, otime, ctime, fee);
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("ParkAddInfo Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://35.160.135.119/add_park_info.php"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String park_add_info_url;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            park_add_info_url = "http://35.160.135.119/add_park_info.php"; // insert the Domain name http://androidtut.comli.com//add_info.php
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)  {

            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

            param.put("pic",args[0]);
            param.put("owner",args[1]);
            param.put("mobile",args[2]);
            param.put("addrs",args[3]);
            param.put("otime",args[4]);
            param.put("ctime",args[5]);
            param.put("fee",args[6]);
            try {
                URL url = new URL(park_add_info_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
                for(Map.Entry item : param.entrySet())
                {
                    sb.append(item.getKey().toString());
                    sb.append("=");
                    String value = item.getValue().toString();
                    if(value.isEmpty())
                    {
                        sb.append("");
                    }else
                    {
                        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));
                    }
                    sb.append("&");
                }
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(pic,"UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(mobile,"UTF-8"));
 stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(addrs,"UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(otime,"UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(ctime,"UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(fee,"UTF-8"));

                String data_string = sb.toString(); =URLEncoder.encode(stringBuilder.toString(),"utf-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "One row of data inserted..";


            } catch (IOException e) {//TODO:check network dialog window
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the log

```
    11/15 23:00:15: Launching app
        No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Android\1113GMDemo1\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
        $ adb shell am force-stop com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo
        $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo.DateAndTime" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
        Connecting to com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo
        I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
        W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
        I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
        I/System.out: Debugger has connected
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8629', transport: 'socket'
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
        I/System.out: debugger has settled (1304)
        I/MultiDex: VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
        I/MultiDex: install
        I/MultiDex: MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk, false)
        I/MultiDex: Detected that extraction must be performed.
        I/MultiDex: Trying to delete old file /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-8.apk.classes2.dex of size 2898496
        I/MultiDex: Deleted old file /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-8.apk.classes2.dex
        I/MultiDex: Trying to delete old file /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-8.apk.classes2.zip of size 934986
        I/MultiDex: Deleted old file /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-8.apk.classes2.zip
        I/MultiDex: Extraction is needed for file /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip
        I/MultiDex: Extracting /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes-1719707400.zip
        I/MultiDex: Renaming to /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip
        I/MultiDex: Extraction success - length /data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip: 934986
        I/MultiDex: load found 1 secondary dex files
        D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip' (bootstrap=0) ---
        D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: --- END 'com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip' (success) ---
        D/dalvikvm: DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-9.apk.classes2.zip': unzip in 69ms, rewrite 772ms
        I/MultiDex: install done
        I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
        I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
        I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
        D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
        W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d3da0)
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo, PID: 16909
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo.DateAndTime}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.addView(NestedScrollView.java:387)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:770)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
        at com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo.DateAndTime.onCreate(DateAndTime.java:86)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: when running on debug mode, you have the logcat (output). nothing appears there?

Comment: + when does the app crushes? immediatly or after some operations?

Comment: Verify your xml layout, the error you got is `ScrollView can host only one direct child`, You have to make sure your scoll view has only one direct child. ( Post your xml if you need more help )

Comment: nothing appears I think..
It crushes immediatly.
Ok I fill check my xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by going to your MainActivity, scrolling down to the part that says setContentView(R.layout.**your_layout_name**); and clicking **your_layout_name** while holding down Ctrl (Windows) or Cmd(Mac). This will take you to your layout file. Here you should see A ScrollView opening tag at the beginning and a closing tag at the end. Simply change this to something more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="This is your first item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="This is your second item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="This is your third item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```